# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setOrder() on boolean

Tags: php, magento

i have try crush Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test and Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test_Collection after clear setOrder('id_celebes','asc'); but error no detected.______________but if i crush Lesson3_Test_Model_Test after clear setOrder('id_celebes','asc'); i found error page

```
<?php
class Lesson3_Test_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function methodblock()
    {
        $retour='';
        /* we are doing the query to select all elements of the celebes table (thanks to our model lesson3/test and we sort them by id */
        $collection = Mage::getModel('lesson3/test')->getCollection()->setOrder('id_celebes','asc');
        /* then, we check the result of the query and with the function getData() */
        foreach($collection as $data)
        {
             $retour .= $data->getData('name').' '.$data->getData('surename').' '.$data->getData('phone').'<br />';
        }
        //i return a success message to the user thanks to the Session.
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess('Congratulation !!');
        return $retour;
     }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Lesson3_Test>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Lesson3_Test>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <lesson3>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Lesson3_Test</module>
                 <frontName>lesson3</frontName>
              </args>
           </lesson3>
       </routers>
       <layout>
         <updates>
              <lesson3>
                   <file>lesson3.xml</file>
               </lesson3>
          </updates>
      </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
      <blocks>
        <lesson3>
          <class>Lesson3_Test_Block</class>
        </lesson3>
      </blocks>
    <models>
        <lesson3>
            <class>Lesson3_Test_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>Lesson3_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </lesson3>
        <lesson3_mysql4>
            <class>Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <test>
                    <table>celebes</table>
                </test>
            </entities>
        </lesson3_mysql4>
    </models>
        <!-- allow the plugin to read and write -->
    <resources>
        <!-- connection to write -->
        <lesson3_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </lesson3_write>
        <!-- connection to read -->
       <lesson3_read>
          <connection>
             <use>core_read</use>
          </connection>
       </lesson3_read>
    </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

```
<?php
class Lesson3_Test_Model_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
     protected function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('lesson3/test');
     }
}
```

```
<?php
class Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
     protected function _construct()
     {
         $this->_init('lesson3/test', 'id_celebes');
     }
}
```

```
<?php
class Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
 {
     protected function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('lesson3/test');
     }
}
```

Comment: i suspect the issue is ||||| <lesson3_mysql4> <class>Lesson3_Test_Model_Mysql4</class> <entities> <test> <table>celebes</table> </test> </entities> </lesson3_mysql4> ||||| because if call table with |||| $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); $connection = $resource->getConnection('core_read'); $result = $connection->query('select * from celebes')->fetchAll(); Zend_Debug::dump($result); |||| on indexController this succes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem on config

```
<resourceModel>Test_mysql4</resourceModel>
```

I changed it with this

```
<resourceModel>test_mysql4</resourceModel>
```

and works